# Disabling IPV6 on Centos6

Tags: networking, centos, xen, centos6

I want to disable IPV6 in the new Centos6 virtual server I have just setup in Xen. I have already followed the instructions [here](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-d47139912868bcb9d754441ecb6a8a10d41781df) and then rebooted/restarted networking.

Update: followed the below, that seems to have worked, but now it hasn't picked up an ipv4 address?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9A:F0:43:47:04:F1 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:941 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:89952 (87.8 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:14
```

Comment: Go ahead and post `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make changes in a few different places.

First, disable IPv6 in the user-land network configuration scripts by modifying the file
`/etc/sysconfig/network`
Make sure to set the variable
`NETWORKING_IPV6=no`

Next disable the ipv6 kernel module. You should be able to create a new modprobe.d file to disable it, or outright blacklist it. So either

1. Create a new file `/etc/modprobe.d/ipv6.conf` containing

> alias net-pf-10 off
>   alias ipv6 off

2. Add the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

> blacklist net-pf-10
>   blacklist ipv6

IPTables is enabled by default, and has a separate service for IPv4 and v6, so we need to disable the v6 version as well.

```
service ip6tables stop
chkconfig ip6tables off
```

In theory, once all this is set up, you should be able to restart networking, and unload the module. However, you may require a full reboot to make sure all the cruft is cleaned up. After doing this I would recommend verifying that the disable took by looking at the loaded modules, your running network config, listening/sockets, etc for any v6 indicators.

Comment: Odd that [the CentOS FAQ](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6#head-d47139912868bcb9d754441ecb6a8a10d41781df) doesn't cover this info, which will really disable IPv6 instead of not.  Thanks Scott.